# How can I make Automapper choose parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following constructors in a HuntMemberBLL class.

```
// Default Constructor
    public HuntMemberBLL()
    {IsNew = true;}

    // Get Constructor
    public HuntMemberBLL(long HuntMemberID)
    {   //DbLoading
        IsNew = false;
    }
```

And I have a HuntMemberDTO class which doesn't have any constructors. The problem is when I try to map to HuntMemberBLL class, Automapper chooses Get constructor instead of the Default constructor. Is there any way to make it use the default constructor instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the constructor that you want to use via the ConstructUsing method. For example something like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config => 
config.CreateMap<HuntMemberDTO, HuntMemberBLL>()
      .ConstructUsing((Func<HuntMemberDTO, HuntMemberBLL>)(x => new HuntMemberBLL()));
```

Comment: I have already tried that, it gives me an error saying "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AutoMapper.IMappingExpression<HuntMemberDTO,HuntMemberBLL>.ConstructUsing(System.Func<AutoMapper.ResolutionContext,HuntMemberBLL>)' and 'AutoMapper.IMappingExpression<HuntMemberDTO,HuntMemberBLL>.ConstructUsing(System.Func<..HuntMemberDTO,HuntMemberBLL>)"

Comment: AutoMapper needs Type Information. Can you try with how I edited my code above now?